# Why won't DataExplorer load?

Tags: support, data-explorer, page-load

I was testing my app, and it didn't seem to load the csv requested from https://data.stackexchange.com/, so I tried visiting the site myself.  It wouldn't load.  I tried again.

It's not loading.  What's wrong with it?  Are they updating the site?  Does this usually happen?

What I'm *thinking* is that they ran out of bandwidth.

**Edit**

The site is back up now, and
I realize I was kind of greedy for expecting 100% uptime.

Comment: What makes your app THAT sensitive to downtime? We obviously try not to bring things down unless necessary or unless something goes wrong, but we also don't really *guarantee* uptime. Your app should gracefully handle any issues on our end.

Comment: Give it some time, no site has 100% uptime. If you see DE down for, say, full hour, then bring it up here.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what the problem is but the site appears down:

Just checked it on: http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/data.stackexchange.com.html

and got:

> Data.stackexchange.com is DOWN It is not just you. The server is not
>   responding...

[image]

Also check on: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/data.stackexchange.com

and got:

> It's not just you! http://data.stackexchange.com looks down from here.

EDIT: **Now it is back online**

Comment: +1 I thought it was just me :)

Comment: @TheWobbuffet, now it is back online